# unable to call asynchronous function inside setInterval function

Tags: javascript, typescript, setinterval

I want to call the asynchronous function which is called from a service class instance inside the `setInterval` function.

```
        class async {

        constructor(public service: Service){}            

            async doSomeAsyncTask(){

               setInterval(await this.service.anotherAsyncTaskInTheServiceClass(),3000); 

       //want to call the inside of setInterval function repeatedly in every 3ms.       
      } 
    }
  }
```

Comment: isn't it because of the this keyword? no need to specify it i guess

Comment: Well you are executing the function, not assigning it and why would you use await?

Answer (score 5):

setInterval expects the first param to be a function, so I think it should be

```
setInterval(async () => { await this.service.anotherAsyncTaskInTheServiceClass() },3000);
```

*Thanks for the correction @Evariste *

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to wrap any operations that can throw exceptions in your async function used as argument to `setInterval`/`setTimer` in a try/catch to avoid un-handled exceptions, see [Async, Promises, and Timers in Node.js](https://blog.atomist.com/javascript-timer-settimeout/).